# form 2555 entry in OLT (online tax)

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am using, or rather *trying for the first time*, [OLT](https://www.olt.com) for my taxes. I am running into a problem with filling out form 2555 that lists more parts than buttons to accomplish those parts. Additionally, in its sequential numbering, part II is missing (see image below). Any idea what is going on?

[image: OLT form 2555 input error]

Comment: You should probably reach out to their customer service

Comment: Sometimes a screen may omit a section on a form if that data can be pulled in from other data already entered. I don't know if that applies to this situation or not.

Comment: This is a question best directed to customer support for the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the [PDF form from the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f2555.pdf)

I found this:

> Next, complete either Part II or Part III. If an item doesn’t apply,
> enter “N/A.” If you don’t give the information asked for, any
> exclusion or deduction you claim may be disallowed.

where part 2 is:

> Part II **Taxpayers
> Qualifying Under Bona Fide Residence Test**
>
> Note: Only U.S. citizens and
> resident aliens who are citizens or nationals of U.S. treaty countries
> can use this test. See instructions.

and Part 3 is:

> Part III **Taxpayers Qualifying Under Physical Presence Test**
>
> Note: U.S.
> citizens and all resident aliens can use this test. See instructions.

My guess is that they asked you questions that determined that Part III applied to you. Somebody else may only see Part II with Part III hidden.

Comment: yes, I think your forensics make the most sense. Eventually I was able to successfully file my taxes using OLT, and their price is certainly right. But the UI surely can use some work